# How to handle code duplication involved with unicode support in c++

Tags: c++, unicode

What is the best way is to handle unicode support in c++ currently?

Say I have a simple function like this:

```
std::wstring window::getTypeW(){
    return createType;
}
```

I can add a simple non-wide function like this:

```
std::string window::getType(){
    std::string stype(createType.begin(),createType.end());
    return stype;
}
```

This is not much of a problem, but when a function gets more complicated, there are many options for the variation.

*Example:*

```
int window::attachMenu(const std::string& str){
    if (veil.menu!=NULL){
        DestroyMenu(veil.menu);
        veil.menu=NULL;
    }

    ulti::element el;
    el.setStr(str);

    recurseElementForMenu(veil.menu,el,this);
    return 1;
}
```

*Options:*

1. We can duplicate the code, making the wide and non-wide variants equally fast.
2. We can do on the fly conversions between string and wstring, eliminating duplicate code.
3. We can use templates in some cases, where appropriate (the only way I know how to make this work would require explicit typing for each function when used)
4. We can use ... macros ... and make the user choose unicode support manually.

*Summary:*

This is meant for my little GUI library, (which is working great, minus deep unicode support) so I want to make the best long term decision- It seems like it would be a nightmare to support hundreds of duplicate functions. But because this is a library I do want to take as little processing time as possible... So conversions seem like a much larger waste.

*Questions:*

Would simply supporting unicode and eliminating non-unicode support entirely would be acceptable in a newer library?

Is there perhaps some way I could get away with making a single function for both unicode and non-unicode?

Is there another way I haven't considered?

Comment: Why do you feel that wide strings are important, or even *necessary* for Unicode support? [Have you not heard of UTF-8?](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: UTF-8 is great, and I am using a UTF-8 library, but this is a GUI library that interacts with winapi- so wide strings to some degree are necessary- though I suppose not necessarily for the end developers... Would you suggest just using UTF-8 strings in the stead of both standard and wide strings?

Comment: `std::string stype(createType.begin(),createType.end());` is jot the correct way to convert a `std::wstring` to a `std::string`. This only works for ASCII characters, but fails for everything else. Use `std::wstring_convert`, or `WideCharToMultiByte()`, or other equivilent function.

Comment: Isn't this what the whole TCHAR thing in Windows is for? Define `tstring` as either `string` or `wstring` depending on whether the UNICODE macro is defined. Then make ASCII and Unicode builds.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious way to handle this is to do so as simply as possible.

Within your system, [use UTF-8. All the time.](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/) When you talk to a system that takes something else, convert your UTF-8 string to whatever that "something else" may be. When a system passes back a string in some other format, convert it almost immediately to UTF-8.

That way, you don't have to have any code duplication within the bounds of your system. Platform-specific formats are used only at the periphery of your system.

Could this impact performance? Possibly. But probably not noticeably, not unless you have an atrociously bad UTF-8-to-UTF-16 converter.

Answer (score 0):

Unify your encoding for any `non-ascii` message, `UTF-8` is recommended. The following is `How-to`:

- Keep your source code file UTF-8 encoded. Use iconv(under Linux, or
  cygwin) to convert the file as UTF-8 encoded file if allowed.
- If the source code file is not UTF-8(or the message part), use
  `LibIconv`(also available on Windows) to convert to UTF-8.